# How can I change just some part of a name in a file in Java?

Tags: java

I have a file called "ParkPhotos.txt" and inside I have 12 names of some parks, for example "AmericanSamoa1989_photo.jpg". I want to replace the "_photo.jpg" to "_info.txt", but I am struggling. In the code I was able to read the file, but I am not sure how to replace it.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileNameChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        readFileValues();

    }

    public static void readFileValues() throws IOException
    {
        try {
            File aFile  = new File("ParkPhotos.txt");
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(aFile);

            while (inFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                String parkNames = inFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(parkNames);
           
            }
           inFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error has occurred");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: inFile.nextLine().replace("_photo.jpg", "_info.txt");

Comment: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/40-string-list could be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a new content and write it to the current file. For example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileNameChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        String newContent = readFileValues();
        writeFileValues(newContent);
    }

    public static String readFileValues() {
        StringBuilder newContent = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = FileNameChange.class.getClassLoader().getResource("ParkPhotos.txt");
            File aFile = new File(url.toURI());
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(aFile);

            while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                String parkName = inFile.nextLine();
                if (parkName == null || parkName.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }
                newContent.append(parkName.replace("_photo.jpg", "_info.txt"))
                        .append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            inFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newContent.toString();
    }

    public static void writeFileValues(String content) throws URISyntaxException {
        URL url = FileNameChange.class.getClassLoader().getResource("ParkPhotos.txt");
        File aFile = new File(url.toURI());
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(aFile)) {
            writer.write(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the file will be written at build folder. For example: example_1/build/resources/main